# iOS app freezes after closing it, then black-screens after closing it again

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, debugging

I'm testing my iOS app on my iPhone 4S (running iOS 6 or lower, I believe), which is a simple web browser. When I double tap the home button, close the app (by pressing and holding it, and clicking the "X" which appears), and click the icon to run it again, the app is frozen on the page it was on before being closed. When I then close and click the icon again, it doesn't load; the app simply stays open as a black screen, and doesn't even crash. How can I solve this problem?

Edit: My iPhone is running iOS 6.0. And I cannot see anything in the logs as I completely stop running the app. I'm new to iOS dev, so please be kind!

Edit 2: Issue solved. See my answer below.

Comment: Excuse me, you are testing on an iPhone and you don't even know what version of iOS it is running? Are you serious?

Comment: You solve your problem by using Xcode to debug your app.

Comment: Gnasher, I edited my original post :) It also more accurately describes the problem now too. I'm new to iOS dev, so my apologies for any  ambiguity! And also, because I destroy the app, Xcode stops monitoring it in the Logs. If I run it through Xcode, it works fine. But if I run it through my phone, it black-screens.

Comment: what do you mean by destroy? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I suppose "destroy" is more Android terminology than iOS! Well, when you completely close an app by double-tapping the home button, pressing and holding the icon, and hitting the "X" which appears on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can suggest you here is to debug your app. Whenever the app opens up after being terminated, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your AppDelegate class is called.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Try putting a breakpoint in there and check whats going on. Apart from this I cannot help you much.

Comment: I've solved the problem. My phone eventually froze, so I reset it by holding the power and home buttons down, and now it resets perfectly fine. Must have been some sort of error during a build. But I will remember your advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by restarting my device (pressing and holding the power and home buttons). It seems the error was in some deep-ingrained code, and not in my own code I had written myself.